# getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

Tags: java, android

I had a NullPointerException when i used the method above, instead of   `getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);`

For future reference, how can I get Android Studio or IntellijIdea to give me a better tip on my mistake. I havent tried `Analyze` -> `Inspect Code`

I received this common mistake from the CommonsGuy sample demos.

It was available in Google's own effectivenavigation Code sample as:

```
// Set up the action bar.
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

Here, my actionBar stayed Null and I just set up

```
if(actionBar != null)
```

statements and the code managed to run, until i changed to the Android Support Library method: `getSupportActionBar()`

This example from google had actually managed to run without showing me the three "Sections Tabs"

Answer (score 0):

Your `Activity` should be extending `AppCompatActivity` to make it possible to use `getSupportActionBar()` method. Also please check if your `Activity`'s theme is not extending from `NoActionBar`.

Comment: I had those bases covered. the problem arose from the luck of sufficient error messages from the compiler. meaning, the compiler did not give off enough information for the problem to be resolved easily,